# Trouble filtering/sorting with paging numbers in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, filtering

I'm having trouble trying to get paging to function correctly while filtering.

When the filters are active the paging numbers are not correct, and it only filters the first page of results. What I want is:

- all items to be considered to start with
- then filter by the text and category filters
- order those filtered results
- limit the results to only show the current page
- update the page number to correctly show the number of pages based on the filter, not all results

Here is the ng-repeat statement i'm using:

```
item in items | 
filter: { name: filters.name, category: filters.category } | 
orderBy: predicate: reverse | 
startFrom: currentPage * pageSize | 
limitTo: pageSize
```

And the html in full:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><a href="" ng-click="predicate='id';reverse=!reverse">#</a></th>
                <th><a href="" ng-click="predicate='name';reverse=!reverse">Name</a></th>
                <th><a href="" ng-click="predicate='category';reverse=!reverse">Category</a></th>
                <th><a href="" ng-click="predicate='date';reverse=!reverse">Date</a></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{name:filters.name,category:filters.category} | orderBy:predicate:reverse | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
                <td>{{ item.id || 'None' }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.name || 'None' }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.category || 'None' }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.date | None' }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage"></pagination>
```

And this is the custom startFrom filter i'm using to get a page of results:

```
.filter('startFrom', function () {
    return function (input, start) {
        return input.slice(start);
    };
});
```

You can see a working version here:

http://kmturley.github.io/angular-bootstrap/app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/yVDZR6Zwo9P8OHT0G2Hr?p=preview

I've changed few things

JS:

```
$scope.updatefilters = function(category)
          {
       $scope.filters.category = category;
       $scope.totalItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items,$scope.filters).length;
        }

        $scope.setPage = function (num) {
            $scope.totalItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items,$scope.filters).length;
            $scope.currentPage = num;
            $scope.pageSize = 5;
            console.log($scope.currentPage, $scope.totalItems);
        };

        $scope.setPage(1);
    })
```

html:

```
<div ui-view="sidebar">
            <div class="filters">
                <h1>Filters</h1>

                <h3>Category</h3>
                <p><a href="" ng-click="updatefilters('')">All Categories</a></p>
                <p><a href="" ng-click="updatefilters('music')">Music</a></p>
                <p><a href="" ng-click="updatefilters('film')">Film</a></p>
                <p><a href="" ng-click="updatefilters('tv')">TV</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: awesome that sent me on the right direction, I also had two other bugs!

startFrom:(currentPage-1)*pageSize and i needed to set items-per-page="pageSize"